# Convert date/time string value to .NET DateTime

Tags: .net, mysql, datetime

i've this string example value:
Sun, 09 May 2010 11:16:35 +0200

I've to insert it into MySql Date/Time field.

How can i convert it into .NET format (or Mysql format), so i can make my INSERT INTO `mydate='2010-05-09 11:16:35'` ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to use `DateTime.Parse()` to create a .NET DateTime object from the string value, as noted by others.

Don't be tempted to do something like:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(" + someDate.ToString() + ")";
```

It's much better to build a parameterized query instead, not just in this case. It also makes sure that if you're trying to insert/update text, you're able to handle quotes correctly (instead of risking a sql injection possibility)

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, 2, @theDate)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", someDate);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The MSDN documentation on the `DateTime.Parse()` method describes in detail how to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: You just got me by seconds ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.DateTime  dateTime = System.DateTime.Parse(YourDate)
```

Then you could do whatever you want like get it in seconds, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) is quite the easiest that comes in my mind in fact.